# how to remake the beginning of the week, not from Sunday, but from Monday

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I use the library to display the calendar, I would like to make the week start on Monday and the calendar is displayed from the current date by 2017

https://github.com/miraan/CalendarDateRangePickerViewController

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7eJ1.png)

changed the locale on russian language, but did not help

```
func getMonthLabel(date: Date) -> String {
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

func getWeekdayLabel(weekday: Int) -> String {
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.calendar = Calendar.current
    components.weekday = weekday
    let date = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: components, matchingPolicy: Calendar.MatchingPolicy.strict)

    if date == nil {
        return "E"
    }

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEEE"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
```

Comment: Post code as text and not as an image and explain what the issue is with your code

Comment: For some reason, in the calendar, the week starts on Sunday, and I would like to start on Monday with the ru_RU locale. As well as problems with the display of dates. I want to get a calendar from the current date to previous years

Comment: Why don't you set `.locale` of `Calendar` then?

Comment: The only calendar which the first weekday is Monday is the iso8601 calendar

Comment: @LeoDabus not work

Comment: Not work is too vague. Why are you using a fixed locale? You should display the weekday name respecting the user device locale and settings.

Comment: What do you need ? What is your actual problem? Are you trying to get the next Monday after now?

Comment: I will reopen your question I should have marked it as unclear

Comment: @LeoDabus, **first weekday is not hardcoded to calendars**, but depends on `Calendar`'s [locale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293340-locale). And indeed if you set `Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")` there you will have `.firstWeekday == 2` (Monday). For all `Calendar.Identifier` cases.

Comment: @LeoDabus The problem was in this part of the code, corrected by 2 and managed to get the desired result. Thank you for the idea

https://yadi.sk/i/7WZ7a7WAQwdJZA

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this part of the code, corrected by 2 and managed to get the desired result.

```
override public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CalendarDateRangePickerCell

    cell.reset()

    let blankItems = getWeekday(date: getFirstDateForSection(section: indexPath.section)) - 1

    if indexPath.item < 7 {

       cell.label.text = getWeekdayLabel(weekday: indexPath.item **+ 2** )

    } else if indexPath.item < 7 + blankItems {

        cell.label.text = ""
```